# ExpressJS - Add functionality by .prototype globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knockout.js

Ok, I'd like you to understand the idea - because maybe there's a better solution to this:

I created some models for expressJS and it's render-engine jade.
But because they're JS-models anyway, I'd like to use them on the client-side: As KnockoutJS-Models.

For that purpose, each model has 2 functions: an enableKO- and disableKO-function.
So far, so good: But now I'm trying to use some logic which I want to use on the server-side and on the client as well.

To get the values - no matter if they're default JS-objects or Knockout-observeables, I've added 2 functions:

```
Function.prototype.getValue = function() { return this(); }
Object.prototype.getValue = function() { return this; }
```

Now I can call model.value.getValue() and I get the value I'm looking for - in theory.
If I actually call the function, the error I get is "500 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded", which is pretty much worthless.

I have defined the 2 functions in my app.js-file, as well as in a js-file which the client will call.

That's the reason for my question: Or is there a better approach to my goal?
Thanks!

Comment: Never extend `Object.prototype` with enumerable properties.

Comment: Alright then, but what's the way I should go?